# What is the difference between tap and map in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I read the difference from the article but the main points look like this.

so with `tap` I can change the variables such as that if I put `x=3+4` then it changes the values of variable then I can say there is one side effect.

But with `map` I can change the value looping each value, isn't it? 
Can you pinpoint what outstanding differences they have?

**tap**

> RxJS tap performs side effects for every value emitted by source Observable and returns an Observable identical to the source Observable until there is no error.

**map**

> map is a RxJS pipeable operator. map applies a given function to each element emitted by the source Observable and emits the resulting values as an Observable

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A mapping function takes a thing and returns another thing. e.g. I can build a function that takes `10` and returns `11`, that takes `11` and returns `12`, etc.

```
const inc = n => n + 1;
```

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) applies such mapping function to all elements of an array but "map" doesn't mean "iteration".

In RxJS, when a data is sent to the stream it goes through a series of operators:

- The `map` operator will simply apply a function to that data and return the result.
- The `tap` operator however takes a data, apply a function to that data but returns the original data, if the function bothered to return a result, `tap` just ignores it.

Here's an example:

- We push `10` to stream `a$`, `tap` just log the value. We know that `console.log` always return `undefined` but that's fine because `tap` simply returns its parameter.
- We push `10` to stream `b$`, it goes through `map(inc)` which applies `inc` to `10` returning `11`.

```js
const a$ = of(10).pipe(tap(n => console.log(`tap: ${n}`)));
const b$ = of(10).pipe(map(inc));

a$.subscribe(n => console.log(`n from a$: ${n}`));
b$.subscribe(n => console.log(`n from b$: ${n}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<script>
const {of} = rxjs;
const {map, tap} = rxjs.operators;

const inc = n => n + 1;
</script>
```

Comment: where can u use tap and where to use map?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and your given example :)

Comment: Simple and plain language, best!

Comment: "if the function bothered to return a result, tap just ignores it.", no, tap will still return the changed result if the emitted value is object, so I can't understand why api said tap will return the same input observable, the question is posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76625648/rxjs-what-is-the-meaning-of-you-can-mutate-objects-as-they-pass-through-the-tap/76626360?noredirect=1#comment135103664_76626360

Comment: That is the same warning as for any functions mutating objects passed as arguments as these are passed as references and not as values.

Answer (score 41):

**Tap** should be Used for Notification, logging non-contextual/critical side effects.

It's like a "peek" into the "pipe". The data stays the same, You can do something with it. Some data goes in, you look, same data comes out.

**Map** is for transformation/mapping of the Data in the "pipe". Some data comes in, different/transformed data comes out.

Edit:

> It's like a "peek"

It is important here, that even though it is "peeking" and not mapping, mutating the object here, will lead to the object being changed. It simply does not require a "return". So even though it appears immutable, side effect causing changes should be avoided.

Comment: no, when emitted data is object, when pass through tap, the output object will be changed.

Answer (score 20):

- The purpose of `tap` is to **execute an action** keeping the same value
  of the observable
- The purpose of `map` is to **transform** the emitted values of the
  observable

```ts
const messagesCount$ = newMessages$
.pipe(tap(messages => notificationService.notify('You have ' + message.length + ' message(s)')))
.pipe(map(messages => messages.length))
```

Answer (score 14):

The `tap` and `map` are both RxJS operators, RxJS operators are just function that performs some manipulation over the data.

Both of them are `pipeable operators` which takes input as Observable, perform some action and return an output observable.

**Difference between map and tap:**

The `map` is a pipeable operator that takes an input observable, performs some manipulation on it and returns a new manipulated observable. For example

```
const source$ = of(1,2,3) // observable which will emit 1,2,3
// It take an input observable and return a new observable which will emit square of input values. 
// So, the output observable will emit 1,4,9
const mapSource$ = of(1,2,3)
                    .pipe(map(value => value * value))
```

The `tap` operator on another hand takes an input observable perform some action and returns the same input observable.

```
const source$ = of(1,2,3) // observable which will emit 1,2,3
// It take an input observable and return a same observable after console value.
// So, the output observable will emit 1,2,3
const tapSource$ = of(1,2,3)
                    .pipe(tap(value => console.log(value)))
```

Comment: where can u use tap and where to use map?

Answer (score 6):

you can think of `tap` operator as a void function that whatever it does to the input value it does not change the original value

```
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// here we are manipulating the input value but the output value of the observable still the same 
const example = source.pipe(
  tap(val => val + 100),
);

// output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

in the other hand if we made any manipulation of the input values of the observable using the `map` operator it will change the output values

```
const example = source.pipe(
  map(val => val + 100)
);

// output: 101, 102, 103, 104, 105
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 1):

I addition to what the others are saying, in Rxjs 7.4 tap now has three more subscribe handlers, so you can use it to get notified on subscribe, unsubscribe and finalize:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/eb26cbc4488c9953cdde565b598b1dbdeeeee9ea#diff-93cd3ac7329d72ed4ded62c6cbae17b6bdceb643fa7c1faa6f389729773364cc

This is great for debugging purposes, so you can use tap to find out much more about what is happening with your stream.

Example:

```
const subscription = subject
.pipe(
  tap({
    subscribe: () => console.log('subscribe'),
    next: (value) => console.log(`next ${value}`),
    error: (err) => console.log(`error: ${err.message}`),
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
    unsubscribe: () => console.log('unsubscribe'),
    finalize: () => console.log('finalize'),
  })
)
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score -1):

TAP, can NOT transform:

```
interval(1000).pipe(tap(el=> el*2)).subscribe(console.log); // 0,1,2,3
```

MAP, CAN transform:

```
interval(1000).pipe(map(el=> el*2)).subscribe(console.log); // 0,2,4,6
```

If you do NOT need to transform the value, just console.log it or run external function to pass the Original value = TAP is good.

If you NEED TO TRANSFORM/CHANGE the value = MAP is the way to go.