# How do I return in a tap on an observable in TypeScript/Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, observable, httprequest

I'm trying to make a method in a service. The method should:

- make a GET call to a REST API
- alters a parameter's solution component (string[]) to include the result of the get call
- Return the altered parameter.

However, I don't want it to come back as an observable because I'm altering the object it returns in the component.

Right now my method looks as follows:

```
private GET_URL = '...';
getSolutions(dog: Dog): Dog {
   let opts = new HttpParams();
   //set params
   this.http.get<Array<string>>(this.GET_URL, {params: opts}).pipe(
      tap(solutions => {
         dog.solutions = solutions;
         return dog
      }),
      catchError(//calls to an error handling method I made)
   )
   return dog
}
```

I'd expect it to enter the tap, alter the solution, and then return in the tap. However, it seems to hit the return down below (which is there just so there's a default return) instead.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup a service method like this

```
getSolutions(dog: Dog): Observable<Dog> {
    return this.http.get<Dog>(this.GET_URL, {params: opts})
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError));;
}
```

Handle error here

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorHandlerService {
  constructor() { }

  public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`
      );
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  // delay
  public delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
}
```

Then in your controller, you get the data like this

```
    this.myService.getSolutions().subscribe((myDog : Dog) => {
      console.log(myDog);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

`tap` doesn't allow you to alter the result, you need to use `map` instead. More on `tap` vs `map`: [What is the difference between tap and map in RxJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295224/what-is-the-difference-between-tap-and-map-in-rxjs)

Also, I'm not sure you want to return `dog` right away, as that would return, before the call was executed and the `dog` parameter was modified:

```
private GET_URL = '...';
getSolutions(dog: Dog): Dog {
   let opts = new HttpParams();
   //set params
   // changed to return stream
   return this.http.get<Array<string>>(this.GET_URL, {params: opts}).pipe(
      map(solutions => { // <- change to map
         dog.solutions = solutions;
         return dog
      }),
      catchError(//calls to an error handling method I made)
   )
   // return dog // this would return before the URL was executed
}
```