# How to transfer an object with data from a subscribed subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a getUser function in the UserDataService service, in which I call the tokens function, get a token and pass it to another getUser function, from which I get a user by his id.

```js
getUser(id: number) {
  return this.sharedDataService.tokens.subscribe((result) => {
    return this.userService
      .getUser(result, id)
      .subscribe((resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
        if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
          return resultService.data;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
  });
}
```

```
export interface User{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

How do I get a User object when calling this function?
This code will not work.

```js
let user = this.userDataService.getUser(1);
```

How to correctly pass objects from such functions?
You can transmit by event, but in this case it is not very convenient.
Maybe you can subscribe to the get User function?

Comment: return in subscribe() is not returning anything

Comment: I've already figured that out. I just don't understand how I can return an object from this function.

Answer (score 2):

In similar cases, it's recommended to return the `Observable` itself (instead of subscribing to it within the `service`), and then `subscribe` to it within the components.

You can try the following:

```js
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getUser(id: number): Observable<User | null> {
  return this.sharedDataService.tokens.pipe(
    switchMap((result) => this.userService.getUser(result, id)),
    map((resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {
      if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
        return resultService.data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

And within the component class, you can get the user object like the following:

```js
this.userDataService.getUser(1).subscribe((user) => {
  // You can use the `user` here...
  console.log(user);
});
```

Or you can assign the `getUser` result to a new `Observable` in the component class, then use it (`subscribe` to it) in the component template using `async` pipe, like the following:

```js
// Component class:
user$: Observable<User>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.user$ = this.userDataService.getUser(1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Component template -->
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
  <!-- You can use `user` object here -->
  <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: In this code I get an error:
The 'null' type cannot be assigned to the 'User' type.

Comment: @alex sorry, my bad. you just need to use `Observable<User | null>` as a return type of `getUser` function, instead of `Observable<User>`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code, but I guess you should do something like this:

```
import { switchMap, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
... 
getUser(id: number) {

   return this.sharedDataService.tokens
   .pipe(
      switchMap(token => this.userService.getUser(token, id)),
      tap(
         (resultService: DataResponse<User>) => {

            if (resultService.status === StatusType.SUCCESSFUL) {
              return resultService.data;
            } else {
              return null;
            }

      }),
    );
```

You also can type your function, depending on what *resultService.data* type is.

For instance, if *resultService.data* is User type, you can type your function as:

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User|null> {
```

Comment: This won't work! returning a value from the `subscribe` method, won't affect the returned value from the `getUser` function itself.

Comment: I don't know where my head was! (facepalm) Of course it wouldn't work, it was a classic rookie mistake! I wasn't awake when I answer the question :)    Now I've just edited it, @Amer, thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: Sorry @Amer, I hadn't seen your reply, where you basically corrected the same thing I've just edited! Now that I look at it more closely, you use **map** and I use a **tap**, but I think the result would be the same, right?

Comment: No, it won't be the same result. Using `tap` doesn't transform the data, and the returned value of the `Observable` will be the type of `this.userService.getUser(token, id)` switched using `switchMap`. However, using `map` will transform the `Observable` type to the new type returned from `map`. Check this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295224/what-is-the-difference-between-tap-and-map-in-rxjs/61295611